# Instead of getting undefined, how can I get the data from the asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

`subject` in `user.subjects = subjects` below is `undefined` instead of being an array of subjects.

Background:
I have three tables - users, subjects, and a relation between users and subjects called users_subjects.

My goal is that the final res should include an array of subject names.

To do this, I need three asynchronous calls.

- Get the users from the users table
- Get the subjects is for each user from the table representing the relation between users and subjects (users_subjects)
- Get the name for each subject id from subject table

My challenge is getting inputing the subject id and receiving the name. *the upper half of addSubjects* is my attempt to solve it, albeit unsuccessfully:

```
   //for every user take its id
    //run its id with tutors-subjects to get all subject id with that user id
    //for each subject id get is subject name through with subjects service
    //add subjects key
    //add each subject to an array
const addSubject = (knexInstance, users, res) => {
  let resultsName = []
    function testIt(subjectsArray) {
       // let resultsName = []
        Promise.all(
            subjectsArray.map((id) =>
                SubjectsServes.getById(knexInstance, id)
                    .then(subjectNameObject => {
                       console.log(subjectNameObject)
                        resultsName.push(subjectNameObject.subject_name)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        //console.log(err)
                    })
            )).then(() => {
                return resultsName
            })
    }

    let results = []

    Promise.all(
        users.map((user) =>
            TutorsSubjectsService.getAllSubjectsForATutor(knexInstance, user.user_id)
            .then(subjectsIdArray => {
                    return testIt(subjectsIdArray)
                })
                .then(sub => {
                    user.subjects = sub
                    results.push(user)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    //console.log(err)
                })
        )).then(() => {

            return res.json(results)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //console.log(err)
        })

}
```

The following code is where it starts - it calls the above function:

```
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        const knexInstance = req.app.get('db');
        UsersService.getAllUsers(knexInstance)
            .then(Users => {
                return addSubject(knexInstance, Users, res)
            })
            .catch(next)
```

**The only problem I have is with the testIt function.** Everything till that point works fine. They're just here for context.

My question is how can I get the correct subjectNames back from `testIt`?

(The return in `testIt` last `then` does not help; the whole function testIt just returns `undefined` as said in the title)

Comment: looks like addSubject takes time to load.

Comment: There's a lot of places where you aren't returning a promise from a function
, which is how you resolve promise values. Are you able to use async/await in this environment?

Comment: I would love to hear more. I was playing around with await/sync before but I wasn't able to solve it. It should work though. (I creating a sever with node and express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const  testIt = (subjectsArray)=> {
       
        return subjectsArray.map((id) => {
            
               return SubjectsServes.getById(knexInstance, id);
               
            }).reduce((acc,el)=>{
            
                acc.push(el); 
                return acc;
                
               },[])
               
           //return array of promises
        
 }
const addSubject = (knexInstance, users, res) => {
  
   
    
    Promise.all(
        users.reduce((acc,el)=>{ 
           acc.push(TutorsSubjectsService.getAllSubjectsForATutor(knexInstance, el.user_id));              return acc; 
          
          },[])
           
        ).then((userResults) => { 
        //resolve all promises userResult is an array of result from promises above

            Promise.all( userResults.reduce((acc,el)=>{
               //for each user create array of promises given the subject list
               acc = acc.concat(testIt(el))
            } ,[]).then((results)=>{
            
               return res.status(200).send(result);
            }).catch( (err)=>{
            
              console.log(err);
              
              return res.status(500).end();
            } )
        })
        .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              
              return res.status(500).end();
        })

}
```

when you .then() it  means you are resolving promises. So nothing return to promise.all.  `Promise.all().then( result=>{} )`
result is an array of output  from promises. You have to chain all promises inside each other. They are async, 2 promises all run concurrently. So your result name will be ambiguous, possibly inital value (empty array)

Comment: I tried to nest it as you suggested: https://repl.it/join/iziieeya-elireiner is there a way I cannot get the name of each subject and not an empty array?

Comment: i edit the answer, and the wayi would have done given that there's no constrain on the resource (memory,cpu ,etc,etc)

Comment: Thank you! I was working on this all day. let me test it throughly tomorrow.

Comment: This was very helpful. My final implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/elireiner/94418f3bf5318088b3a607d26621617f